# Clickonce install illegal character error 0x80070246

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I have one user trying to install a clickonce application and they're getting the error below. Is this a Windows configuration issue or something else?

> Activation of
> \usflnas1.wst.corproot.com\Home$\714099\Downloads\AgentToolbox
> (5).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were
> detected: + An illegal character was encountered. For a multi-byte
> character set this includes a lead byte without a succeeding trail
> byte. For the Unicode character set this includes the characters
> 0xFFFF and 0xFFFE. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070246)

Comment: It is recommended that you clear the ClickOnce cache of the problem machine. Will other users have problems when downloading? Try modifying the address you provided. Try to shorten the length, and note that it is best not to have any characters other than \. This problem is more like a problem with the client itself.

Comment: Thanks Jiale! Clearing the cache worked. I had to do that before and didn't think about it this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to solve this issue is to `clear the ClickOnce cache of the problem machine.`